# How to improve performance in hive

Tags: hive

I am running below query which is around 2 million in hive. Is there any way to improve the performance? The source hive table is partition column of created_date

```
 select t.id,
    case when t.amt_1_rank < 0.3*f.amt_1_count then t.amt_1 else null end as amt_1,
    case when t.amt_2_rank < 0.3*f.amt_2_count then t.amt_2 else null end as amt_2,
..
..
..  -- Like wise 30 columns e.g. amt_3,amt_3...
     from (
    select a.id,
    a.amt_1,
    row_number() over (ORDER BY cast(a.amt_1 AS DECIMAL(8,7)) DESC) AS amt_1_rank,
    a.amt_2,
    row_number() over (ORDER BY cast(a.amt_2 AS DECIMAL(8,7)) DESC) AS amt_2_rank
    from source_table a WHERE created_date='2017-10-15' )t
    join 
    ( 
    SELECT count(case when amt_1='.' then null else 1 end) AS amt_1_count,
    count(case when amt_2='.' then null else 1 end) AS amt_2_count,
..
..

    FROM   source_table
    WHERE  created_date='2017-10-15' 
    ) f
```

Comment: apply compression codecs on the table this will take much more less time

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without join:

```
select t.id,
    case when t.amt_1_rank < 0.3*t.amt_1_count then t.amt_1 else null end as amt_1,
    case when t.amt_2_rank < 0.3*t.amt_2_count then t.amt_2 else null end as amt_2,
..
..
..  -- Like wise 30 columns e.g. amt_3,amt_3...
     from (
    select a.id,
           a.amt_1,
           row_number() over (ORDER BY cast(a.amt_1 AS DECIMAL(8,7)) DESC) AS amt_1_rank,
           a.amt_2,
           row_number() over (ORDER BY cast(a.amt_2 AS DECIMAL(8,7)) DESC) AS amt_2_rank,
           count(amt_1_flag) over()                                        AS amt_1_count,
           count(amt_2_flag) over()                                        AS amt_2_count
      from 
           (select a.*,
                   case when amt_1='.' then null else 1 end as amt_1_flag,
                   case when amt_2='.' then null else 1 end as amt_2_flag
              from source_table a WHERE created_date='2017-10-15' 
            )a  

           )t
```

Comment: How you think that it will work for around 20-30 columns like this

Comment: @user2672739 why not. Please explain your point, I don't understand completely. I just proposed to remove join and one unnecessary table scan

Comment: The problem here is row_number over by clause on each columns will take time i guess. Because there are around 30 such columns

Comment: Or to be precise it there any alternate approch ?

Comment: @user2672739 No that I know of, unfortunately.